# Error while querying DBPedia using Apache Jena

Tags: java, sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia, apache-jena

```
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecution;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QuerySolution;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSetFormatter;

public class sparq {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws SQLException
{

    String queryString=
            "PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>"+
            "PREFIX category: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:>"+
            "PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>"+
            "PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>"+
            "select distinct ?super where {"+
                  "?super (^skos:broader){0,4} category:Nationalist_parties, category:New_Delhi"+
                "}";



            // now creating query object

            com.hp.hpl.jena.query.Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);
            // initializing queryExecution factory with remote service.
            // **this actually was the main problem I couldn't figure out.**
            QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService("http://dbpedia.org/sparql", query);


            //after it goes standard query execution and result processing which can
            // be found in almost any Jena/SPARQL tutorial.
            try {
                com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect();
                while(results.hasNext())
                {
                    QuerySolution s=results.nextSolution();
                    String strg=s.getResource("?x").toString();
                    System.out.println(strg);
                }
                //ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results, query);  
            }
            finally {
               qexec.close();
            }

}
}
```

While Executing the above query using Eclipse-Apache Jena,I get the following ERROR.But if the same query is fired on webservice page of dbpedia sparql virtuso, It gives a desired result.

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.jena.riot.system.stream.JenaIOEnvironment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryParseException: Encountered " "{" "{ "" at line 1, column 249.
Was expecting one of:
    <IRIref> ...
    <PNAME_NS> ...
    <PNAME_LN> ...
    <BLANK_NODE_LABEL> ...
    <VAR1> ...
    <VAR2> ...
    "true" ...
    "false" ...
    <INTEGER> ...
    <DECIMAL> ...
    <DOUBLE> ...
    <INTEGER_POSITIVE> ...
    <DECIMAL_POSITIVE> ...
    <DOUBLE_POSITIVE> ...
    <INTEGER_NEGATIVE> ...
    <DECIMAL_NEGATIVE> ...
    <DOUBLE_NEGATIVE> ...
    <STRING_LITERAL1> ...
    <STRING_LITERAL2> ...
    <STRING_LITERAL_LONG1> ...
    <STRING_LITERAL_LONG2> ...
    "(" ...
    <NIL> ...
    "[" ...
    <ANON> ...
    "+" ...
    "*" ...
    "/" ...
    "|" ...
    "?" ...

    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.lang.ParserSPARQL11.perform(ParserSPARQL11.java:102)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.lang.ParserSPARQL11.parse$(ParserSPARQL11.java:53)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.lang.SPARQLParser.parse(SPARQLParser.java:37)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory.parse(QueryFactory.java:148)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory.create(QueryFactory.java:80)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory.create(QueryFactory.java:53)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory.create(QueryFactory.java:41)
    at sparq.main(sparq.java:49)
```

**But If the same query runs on using DBPedia Virtuso sparql on web.It gives the result.**
I am new to Apche jena Please Help!!!!

Comment: Yes, Virtuoso accepts non standard syntax.  Your query isn't actually legal SPARQL 1.1 (or SPARQL 1.0).  You can check whether your query is legal with [sparql.org's query validator](http://sparql.org/query-validator.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Virtuoso accepts non standard syntax. The **{n,m}** syntax was in one of the earlier proposals for property paths, but it did not get accepted into the SPARQL 1.1 standard.  As a result, your query isn't actually legal SPARQL 1.1 (or SPARQL 1.0). You can check whether your query is legal with [sparql.org's query validator](http://sparql.org/query-validator.html).

I think you can also use Jena's API to ask it to *not* validate the query first, in which case you'll be able to send your query. See, for instance, [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26008521/sparql-query-error-with-optiontransitive-on-jena#comment40744518_26013093):

> If you are using Jena to send a query with Virtuoso-specific features,
>   you need to direct create a QueryEngineHTTP (which is a
>   QueryExecution) and provide just the 2 strings, endpoint and query
>   string. Otherwise, Jena validates the query locally but it isn't valid
>   SPARQL hence it fails. —  [AndyS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/757100/andys) [Sep 24 '14 at 10:48](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26008521/sparql-query-error-with-optiontransitive-on-jena#comment40744518_26013093)

or this answers.semanticweb.com question: [jena throws QueryParsingException on correct but non-standard SPARQL](http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/19935/jena-throws-queryparsingexception-on-correct-but-non-standard-sparql).  In that question, OP found a solution by creating a QueryEngineHTTP directly, with code like this:

```java
QueryEngineHTTP qe = new QueryEngineHTTP("http://dbpedia.org/sparq","select ...");
ResultSet rs = qe.execSelect();
```

Comment: In this case, QueryFactory.create(..., Syntaxt.syntaxARQ) may work because Jena ARQ accepts {} as an extension.  Virtuoso specific extensions are not covered.

Comment: Then how to convert the below query in the sparql standard format.Is there way to rewrite it in a standard form
**"select distinct ?super where {"+
                  "?super (^skos:broader){0,4} category:Nationalist_parties, category:New_Delhi"+
                "}";**

Comment: @Joshua Thankyou for the great help.The above code worked for the non standard query of sparql.I also found interesting that there is also no need to define prefix.

Comment: I have the same problem with 'Op op = Algebra.compile(query)'... any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the problem as

```
void std_query()
    {
        String query = "select distinct ?super where {?super (^skos:broader){0,3} category:Nationalist_parties, category:New_Delhi}";
        QueryEngineHTTP qe = new QueryEngineHTTP("http://dbpedia.org/sparql", query);

        try {
            com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSet results = qe.execSelect();
            while(results.hasNext())
            {
                QuerySolution s=results.nextSolution();
                String strg=s.getResource("?super").toString();
                System.out.println("########### Standard Sparql Result #########");
                System.out.println(strg);
            }
            //ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results, query);  
        }
        finally {
           qe.close();
        }
    }
```